# shiny app unreachable by shinyloadtest library

Tags: r, shiny, load-testing, shinyapps, rsconnect

I am trying to load-test a shiny app on RStudio Connect. The [shinyloadtest](https://rstudio.github.io/shinyloadtest/) library claims to be able to load-test shiny apps on Rstudio Connect. I have installed this library and the shinnycannon app/library. I try to run

`shinyloadtest::record_session("https://rsconnect-dev.the_rest.io/of/my/url/")`

and receive the following error:

**Target URL https://rsconnect-dev.the_rest.io/of/my/url/ does not appear to be a Shiny application.**

The actual url is different but starts with *https://rsconnect-dev*. It appears that one of the internal functions  ( [detect.R](https://rdrr.io/github/rstudio/shinyloadtest/src/R/detect.R)) is saying that the url is the incorrect format. Have you found a way to bypass this?

Answer (score 2):

You probably found a solution but for future shinyloadtest users it could help.

Shiny applications hosted on shinyapps.io can't be reached with `shinyloadtest` package.
Try with this shiny example [url = "https://daattali.com/shiny/mimic-google-form/"](http://url%20=) it should works.